# Clipping Buffers

Tags: python, arcmap, geoprocessing, buffer, clip

I have buffered a line shapefile where many lines are intersecting but not broken at intersections. I am trying to select each record in the buffer file and clip all intersecting polygons in the same layer. Hoping this can be done in Python, but I am a real beginner.

Comment: What do you want to clip the buffer polygons by? Another polygon file? It would be odd to try and clip polygons by overlapping polygons in the same featureclass. What is your desired output - would dissolving the buffer achieve the desired results?